# Is there a way to use the higher of your wits or dexterity to determine base defense?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

In Vampire: The Requiem you use the *lower* of your Dexterity or Wits to determine your base defense. Is there is a merit/power/devotion/etc. that allows you to use the *higher* of the two instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Fighting Style: Boxing (World of Darkness, page 110)

**Duck and Weave** (••): Your character is trained to instinctively duck and evade an opponent’s blows. Use *the higher of your character’s Dexterity or Wits* to determine his Defense when dealing with Brawl-based attacks only (not against Weaponry attacks). If a combination of Brawl- and Weaponry-based attacks is focused on your character in the same turn, use his normal Defense against both.

Answer (score 4):

In **World of Darkness: Slasher**, a book often paired with **Hunter: the Vigil** and designed for creating characters in the mold of movie antagonists like Jason Voorhees, Freddy Krueger, Hannibal Lecter, or the like, there's the Atavism merit (p.127):

> **Prerequisite:** Dexterity 3 or Wits 3, Intelligence 2 or below.
>
> Like an animal, you use the higher of your Dexterity and Wits to determine your Defense. You suffer a -2 modifier on non-confrontational Social rolls. If you raise your Intelligence above 2 then you no longer benefit from this Merit.

It's at character creation only, and I believe restricted to this unusual template.

Comment: Hello, Phillip, and welcome to the site.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about this, like make it clear which book this is from?

Comment: Or alternately: could a WOD player edit this to be a quote and describe it briefly in a way that doesn't make this 100% just a quote?

Comment: @doppelgreener Work better?